# x86 Assembly (How to display Counter?)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dos

The purpose of this code is to display the title "hello World" with a numerical value under it that denotes the number of times that the INC counter has been used. If you run this code, the character string is displayed with the letter K under it(I need a number)in MS DOS. As a side note, register D cannot be used and my assigned memory location is 899. So basically I just need help with figuring out why I am getting a letter(or some other random char) instead of a number every time I run the program. I assume my issue is after the first INT 21 but I am not 100% sure. I would love some input on this and maybe a correction if possible. Here is my code:

```
debug
a100
MOV cL, 02
MOV AL, [0899]
MOV BL, [0900]
SUB AL, BL
MOV BL, 0
JGE 115
INC BL
ADD AL, CL
JMP 10D
MOV [0899], AL
MOV DX, 054B
MOV AH, 09
INT 21
ADD BL, 30
MOV CL, BL
MOV AH, 02
INT 21
INT 20

e 054B "Hello World" 0d 0a "$"

g=100
```

Comment: What did you expect to be printed? The method of adding 30h to get a digit only works for single-digit numbers (i.e. 0..9). If your number is >= 10 you need to repeatedly divide by 10 and output the remainder + 30h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INT 21 FN 02` expects an ASCII-character in register `DL` (**not** `BL` or `CL`). `DL` was set with `MOV DX, 054B` to 4Bh, the ASCII-code for  'K'.

I suggest [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) to check the right use of `INT 21h`. The description of `INT 21 FN 02` can be found under "Int 21/AH=02h".

BTW: Consider that **every** number in DEBUG.EXE is hexadecimal! 0899 is 2201 decimal and 0900 is 2304 decimal, and after 0899 comes 089A (not 0900).

I don't know the initial values of [0899] and [0900] and suspect there are no ones. You can initialise it in the same way as the "Hello..."-string:

```
e 899 5
e 900 10
```

Comment: So which interrupt is the most useful? I can move the register BL into another register other than CL but if I change MOV CL, BL into MOV DL, BL, I simply get another character. And I checked your link but I am unsure which form of INT 21h I should be using since I am just starting with assembly language.

Comment: @alex786: Take a look at my upgraded answer.